# Accessing an ALREADY running process, with Python

Tags: python, process, operating-system, maya

**Question:** Is there a way, using Python, to access the stdout of a running *process*? This process has *not* been started by Python.

**Context:** There is a program called *mayabatch*, that renders out images from 3D Maya scene files. If I were to run the program from the command line I would see progress messages from *mayabatch*. Sometimes, artists close these windows, leaving the progress untracable until the program finishes. That led me along this route of trying to read its stdout after it's been spawned by a foreign process.

**Background:**

- OS: Windows 7 64-bit

**My research so far:** I have only found questions and answers of how to do this if it was a subprocess, using the `subprocess` module. I also looked briefly into `psutil`, but I could not find any way to read a process' stdout.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You could use a socket with a pre-known port, and pipe output to it if connected, no?

Comment: Using native OS services -- this is going to be a challenge and will be entirely dependant on what OS you are using. But it sounds like the problem is simpler than that. It sounds like `mayabatch` has a mechanism to tell you the status of already running programs...and it sounds like it's a command line utility. Why just script it's execution and parse it's output?

Comment: On Linux you can (sort of) do this with `strace`. Perhaps there is a Windows equivalent?

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. They were very useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can [get to the stdout of a process outside of the code that created it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603808/pipe-outputstdout-from-running-process-win32api)

The lazy way to is just to pipe the output of `mayabatch` to a text file, and then poll the text file periodically in your own code so it's under your control, rather than forcing you to wait on the pipe (which is especially hard on Windows, since Windows [`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) doesn't work with the pipes used by subprocess.

I think this is what maya does internally too: by default mayaBatch logs its results to a file called `mayaRenderLog.txt` in the user's Maya directory.

If you're running mayabatch from the command line or a bat file, you can funnel stdout to a file with a `>` character:

```
  mayabatch.exe "file.ma" > log.txt
```

You should be able to poll that text file from the outside using standard python as long as you only open it for reading. The advantage of doing it this way is that you control the frequency at which you check the file.

OTOH If you're doing it from python, it's a little tougher unless you don't mind having your python script idled until the mayabatch completes. The usual subprocess recipe, which uses `popen.communicate()` is going to wait for an end-of-process return code:

```
 test = subprocess.Popen(["mayabatch.exe","filename.mb"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 print test.communicate()[0]
```

works but won't report until the process dies.  But you calling `readlines` on the process's stdout will trigger the process and report it one line at a time:

```
 test = subprocess.Popen(["mayabatch.exe","filename.mb"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
 reader = iter(test.subprocess.readlines, "")
 for line in reader:
     print line
```

More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417546/constantly-print-subprocess-output-while-process-is-running)

Comment: I will try these and let you know. I am pretty sure these are the best ways to go about this.

Comment: How the heck did SO let me post two identical copies?

Comment: Does not work at least in python3: "AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'subprocess'"