# How to observe made Windows System Changes by a Program

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, registry

I just came up with a Question thats bugging me.
I would like to create or find a Program that can observe filesystem changes and registry etc. Changes made by another Executable.
Like Starting a Program through Another and observing the windows api calls or something.

Is that possible? And how would I go about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want an *existing* tool sysinternals process monitor; http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb795533.aspx / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833972/how-does-sysinternals-processmonitor-work

Comment: These tools look promising, especially Process Explorer and Process Manager. I will look a little deeper. If I wanted to use something like dll injection can I observe and log the windows api calls? I have seen some programs observing text write calls etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this api http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx
This api is limited and if your task is out of scope of this api you must go in minifilter driver wonderland.