# FileSystemWatcher program works on the computer where the project is compiled. The exe does not work on any other

Tags: c#, windows, file-watcher

Ive made a program which is looking at the c drive during an installation of another piece of software. This is to detect the files being installed and where.

It works on the computer where i build the project, but not on any other machine.

The machines where i tried the executable on does have .net 4.8 installed.

Im totally out of ideas now.

Does anyone know what this could be

Thank You.

Comment: 1) on the other computer, are you also installing to drive c: ?  2) be aware, under busy conditions FSW may not alert you of all file activity

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. Yes i am installing to drive c, and the computer has a very basic install. No extra software to minimize ressource usage.

Comment: Did you ask it to monitor the whole C: drive? There are a lot of places where you cannot look at if you are not an administrator and even with that privilege there are some place that remains forbidden. Also the C: is usually the system drive and the whole OS is writing there its stuff.

Comment: TY for you input. Yes the whole C: drive. The executable is run with administrator rights, and the places that remains forbidden we dont need to look. I know there is a lot of activity, but im storing it in a list for later processing, and the software can keep up :)

Comment: I'd use [`Process Monitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon#:~:text=Process%20Monitor%20is%20an%20advanced%20monitoring%20tool%20for,session%20IDs%20and%20user%20names,%20reliable%20process) for this rather than try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: TY for you answer. I cant, cause i need to do further handling of the files that is a result of the system watch. This is only a very small tool in a big Eco system.

Comment: If you can't using rocess Monitor like Matthew said, you might want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4834010/585968) that explains how the tool works.  It doesn't use the FSW but rather _"...file system driver driver that creates and attaches filter device objects to target file system device objects..."_.  As mentioned, the `FSW isn't a bullet-proof solution`

Comment: TY for you answer MickyD, im going to look into that.

Comment: @KimSandberg not a problem good sir.  I myself wish the FSW was like how the old Time Machine worked on OSX, it picked up all file changes :)